# compare two text files (order does not matter) and output the words the two files have in common to a third file

Tags: python

I just started programming and I am trying to compare two files that look like this:

```
file1:
tootsie roll
apple
in the evening

file2:
hello world
do something
apple

output:
"Apple appears x times in file 1 and file 2"
```

I am honestly stumped. I have tried creating dictionaries, lists, tuples, sets and I cannot seem to get the output I want. The closest I got was having the lines outputted as exactly as shown for file1/file2.

I have tried several snippets of code from here and I cannot seem to get any of them to output what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the last bit of code that I tried and it did not give me any output to my third file.

```
f1 = open("C:\\Users\\Cory\\Desktop\\try.txt", 'r')
f2 = open("C:\\Users\\Cory\\Desktop\\match.txt", 'r')
output = open("C:\\Users\\Cory\\Desktop\\output.txt", 'w')

file1 = set(f1)
file2 = set(f2)
file(word,freq)
for line in f2:
    word, freq = line.split()
    if word in words:
        output.write("Both files have the following words: " + file1.intersection(file2))
f1.close()
f2.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: What output exactly do you want?

Comment: I want my third file to have an output of each word that matches in the file (example would be if apple is anywhere in file 1 and apple is anywhere in file 2, I would get an output of Apple: x (x = number of times apple appears in both files) and then I want to know how many of that word is in both files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all those loops - if the files are small (i.e., less than several hundred MB), you can work with them more directly:

```
words1 = f1.read().split()
words2 = f2.read().split()
words = set(words1) & set(words2)
```

`words` will then be a `set` containing all the words those files have in common. You can ignore case by using `lower()` before splitting the text.

To have a count of each word as you mention in a comment, simply use the `count()` method:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as output:
    for word in words:
        output.write('{} appears {} times in f1 and {} times in f2.\n'.format(word, words1.count(word), words2.count(word))
```